# Building mod_jk 1.2.48 fails on fedora-server 37

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, build, mod-jk

Fedora-server37 new install

- dnf install httpd (2.4.57)
- dnf install mod_ssl
- dnf install
- httpd-devel (2.4.57)
- download tomcat-connectors-1.2.48-src.tar.gz to /home/tmp
- tar -xvf tomcat-connectors-1.2.48-src.tar.gz
- dnf install redhat-rpm-config
- ./configure -with-apxs=/usr/bin/apxs
- make

mod_jk.so is not created. The error I get:

- /usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option 'specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld'
- error:ld returned 1 exit status

Can you shed some light on why this fails and what do I need to do differently to get mod_jk.so created?

The tomcat-connector installation instructions seem easy... so I'm at a loss.
Any help is greatly appreciated
TIA
Rick

I also tried fedora-server38 - same failure
I also tried tomcat-connectors-1.2.37 - same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. The options that cause the error are located in apache-2.0/Makefile. Around line 25, starting with `APXSLDFLAGS=` there are two appearances of something with `-Wl,-specs=...`. Removed both of them and make could run without problems.